# Конвертация pdf сканов в txt на русском

Tags: python, pdf

Пытаюсь извлечь текст из pdf документов со сканера(изображения внутри). Для этого использую pdftotext python. Программа пытается записать русский текст английскими буквами.
Также пытался использовать агрументы`pdftotext -enc UTF-8 file.pdf`
далее пытался это сделать с помощью утилиты poppler-utils https://pypi.org/project/poppler-utils/  результат тот же.
Устновил  farm-haystack [https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack,код](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack,%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) из туториала возвращает ошибку `No module named 'haystack.indexing`.
Есть варианты как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конечном итоге лучшим решением оказалось установить Adobe Acrobat Reader,  конвертирует намного медленнее модулей python, но конвертирует картинку в текст отлично. Дополнительный плюс в том, что удобен для конвертации большого количества файлов.

Answer (score 2):

Кажется, нет поддержки [textract](http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) в Windows, но если вы ищете простое решение для windows / python 3, проверьте пакет [tika](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python), действительно прямолинейный для чтения PDF-файлов.

> Tika-Python - это привязка Python к службам Apache Tika ™ REST,
> позволяющая непосредственно вызывать Tika в сообществе Python.

```
from tika import parser # pip install tika

raw = parser.from_file('sample.pdf')
print(raw['content'])
```

*Обратите внимание, что Tika написана на Java, поэтому потребуется установленная среда выполнения Java.*

пример `textract`:

```
import textract
text = textract.process("path/to/file.extension")
```

[pymupdf](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/):

```
import fitz  # this is pymupdf

with fitz.open("my.pdf") as doc:
    text = ""
    for page in doc:
        text += page.getText()

print(text)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Прошу прощения что не указал, использую Linux для этого.
Tika отлично сработал для pdf с русским текстом, перед запуском была ошибка с кодировкой, добавил в начало кода  " # -*- coding: latin-1 -*-  "
Но вот картинку с текстом документа возвращает как и все остальные парсеры, а именно русский текст английскими буквами, возможно есть дополнительные настройки?

Comment: Также попробовал textract и pymupdf , тот же результат
вот пример возврата

(MMH3KOHOMPA3BMTH5I POCCMM) 
IIPMKA3 
Mocr<Ba

ссылка на один из файлов, который пытаюсь спарсить 
https://www.cbr.ru/Queries/UniDbQuery/File/90134/79